# How to highlight the current Beamer bullet/text in different color?

Tags: latex, beamer

I have a code below. And I want to highlight the current formula in red while others are in black. many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\title{Beamer Template}
\author{TeXstudio Team}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    
        \begin{itemize}
        \item bla
        \pause  \item \textcolor{red}{redbla}
        \pause  \item \textcolor{red}{redbla but the I want to see the second redbla in \textcolor{black}{black.}}
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can highlight the current item in red by using the `<alert@+>` overlay specification:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
    
        \begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]
        \item bla
          \item redbla
         \item redbla but the I want to see the second redbla in black.
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]